# Can I use my passport card in the SENTRI lane on the Mexican border?

Tags: global-entry, trusted-traveler, sentri

I have Global Entry and my car registered in SENTRI.  I know you're supposed to have an actual Global Entry card to use the land port of entry. But they enrolled my passport book when I signed up so I could just use that at the kiosks at the airport.

I'm wondering if I can register my passport card to my Global Entry membership and use that instead of applying for the Global Entry card at the SENTRI lane and having one more thing to possibly lose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. [You will need a SENTRI or Global Entry card](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1295/kw/ready%20lane) to use the SENTRI lane. If you need to [request a card](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1228/kw/global%20entry%20card), you can do that online, though it takes up to 4-6 weeks to receive one in the mail.

Some border crossings have "[Ready Lanes](http://www.latimes.com/travel/mexico/la-tr-spot-tijuana-border-20171203-story.html)," which can be accessed with a passport card. Slower than SENTRI, but potentially faster than the regular lanes.